# How can i make glitch text easier

Tags: javascript

I was trying to make function that will replace every value from alphabet (english) to a glitch text. This don't work to upper case. How can I make this without writing a lot of code like here?

I was trying replace but its a lot of code:

```js
function GLITCH() {
  document.getElementById("GLITCH").onclick = function() {
    var gluwny6 = document.getElementById("MainText");
    gluwny6.value = gluwny6.value.replace(/a/gi, "a̵͎͕͖̯͘ͅ");
    gluwny6.value = gluwny6.value.replace(/b/gi, "b̸̺͎̅̀͗̚");
    gluwny6.value = gluwny6.value.replace(/c/gi, "c̷̛̹̣͓̼̻̃͂̓̔͛");
    gluwny6.value = gluwny6.value.replace(/d/gi, "d̸̜̻͎̥̍͛̍̾");
    gluwny6.value = gluwny6.value.replace(/e/gi, "ȩ̴͓̼̺̪̯̝̿͆͒");
    gluwny6.value = gluwny6.value.replace(/f/gi, "f");
    gluwny6.value = gluwny6.value.replace(/g/gi, "g");
    gluwny6.value = gluwny6.value.replace(/h/gi, "h̴̛̰̱̪́̔̈́̑̆̀͘");
    gluwny6.value = gluwny6.value.replace(/i/gi, "i̸͚̼̇̃");
    gluwny6.value = gluwny6.value.replace(/j/gi, "j̵̰̺͎̫̳̭͚̫̆̍̋ͅ");
    gluwny6.value = gluwny6.value.replace(/k/gi, "k̶̮̼̦̻̗̝͚̄͑͜͜ͅ");
    gluwny6.value = gluwny6.value.replace(/l/gi, "l̷̢̗͉̭̩̩͓̹̤͝ͅ");
    gluwny6.value = gluwny6.value.replace(/m/gi, "m̶̭͍̘̳̱̭̋͆͐̋̏̀͜");
    gluwny6.value = gluwny6.value.replace(/n/gi, "n̶̻̤̝̥̹̗̈́̍̾̂̈̓͗͘͜͝");
    gluwny6.value = gluwny6.value.replace(/o/gi, "o̸͖̘͛̓͐̿");
    gluwny6.value = gluwny6.value.replace(/p/gi, "p̷̻̘̥̳̯̻͈̆̐̐̾̉̾͌͂̌̚͜");
    gluwny6.value = gluwny6.value.replace(/r/gi, "r̶̺̖̼̖̰͕̽͐̏̒͗͒̈");
    gluwny6.value = gluwny6.value.replace(/s/gi, "s̵͙̼͎̳̑̇̊̍");
    gluwny6.value = gluwny6.value.replace(/t/gi, "t̵̢̡͓͚̬̥̺͉̩͖́̄̂̀̆̈͂");
    gluwny6.value = gluwny6.value.replace(/u/gi, "u");
    gluwny6.value = gluwny6.value.replace(/w/gi, "ẅ̶̖̣́̉̕");
    gluwny6.value = gluwny6.value.replace(/y/gi, "ý̸̢̻̳̣͓̘͐̾̉͘̕");
    gluwny6.value = gluwny6.value.replace(/z/gi, "z̸͓̟̑͒̕");
  }
}

GLITCH();
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 200px;
  height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<button id="GLITCH">Glitch</button>
<textarea id="MainText">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwzy

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</textarea>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Create an object which has 52 keys, one per latin-alphabet lower and upper case character, and the corresponding value should be its replacement. Then write a loop that makes the replacements.

Comment: Make the regexp match any letter. Then use a function as the replacement, and have it look up the letter-to-glitch mapping in an object.

Comment: simple search for zalgo text generator turns up https://zalgo.org/lunicode.js